# Chrome Dev Tools - search in html doc not working with equal sign and quotation mark in between

Tags: search, google-chrome-devtools

I have this problem since a long time in Chrome Dev Tools: I'm using Chrome 63 here, but I'm shure I had it also 5 years ago.

(**hint:** the square brackets around the search examples do NOT belong to the search strings)

**Description:** I want to search for something like **[id="maindiv"]**, but it always says "0 of 0" found.

When searching **[="]** it works, as you see in **screenshot 1**.

But if I only add one character before or after this two (="), nothing gets found.  (**screenshot 2**)

I searched around if anyone else has this problem, nothing found also ..
Is there a workaround, or is this a bug?

Thanx for thinking about it !

[image]

Ctrl+F Search not working:
[image]

Comment: Chrome doesn't search across name=value boundary, it looks [inside one entity only](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/inspector/InspectorDOMAgent.cpp?type=cs&q=performsearch+-file:test+-file:/Debug+lang:cpp&sq=package:chromium&l=997). When your query ends with `"` it simply switches into attribute search mode.